# how to install CoolCtrls6.bpk and TMSC6.bpk in borland c++

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I am using Borland C++Builder 6 for development.  I want to install  `CoolCtrls6.bpk` and `TMSC6.bpk` packages in my IDE.

1. Where do I get these packages?
2. How do I install them in C++Builder 6?

Comment: follow `Component|Install Package...|Add...`

Comment: I don't know what `CoolCtrls` is, but [TMS](https://www.tmssoftware.com) is a 3rd party suite of packages that you need to purchase and download before you can install it.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps below to install component into the palette:

1. Select Component|Install Packages or Install component
2. Click the Add button and multi-select the design time packages you want to install then click Ok.

Sometimes the method described above can’t be used to install component.As some components require compiling & adding it into the existing borland packages.In such case you have to check the README or INSTALL instructions of that particular component.

Comment: but i dont have these packages in my design packages list.

Comment: Where will i get those packages?